# Trying to convert an char to integer

Tags: c++

So i'm trying to produce the sum of the variable `date` of type char in the following code using the `atoi()` function. But when doing so it returns this error message: `test.cpp:9:25: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]` and i can't seem to figure out what the problem is, help would be greatly appriciated.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int calcNumber(const char* date, const int arraySize) 
{
    int sum(0);
    for (int count=0; count<arraySize; count++) {
        sum += atoi(date[count]); 
    }
    return sum;
}
int main()
{
    char date[] = "131083";

    cout << calcNumber(date, sizeof(date) / sizeof(date[0])); 
}
```

Comment: Simply use `atoi(date);` instead of your function.

Comment: @user0042 Sorry but I may have worded it wrongly... I'm trying to iterate trough the array of numbers and add them together producing a sum

Comment: See here how [std::atoi()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) works. To build the sum yourself use `sum += date[count] - '0';`

Comment: The `atoi` function is for strings, not for characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [std::atoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) function expects a `const char*` type. When dereferencing a pointer of type `const char*` with the `[]` operator you are supplying the `char` type. That being said what you need there is the [std::strlen](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) function to determine the length of your character array `-1` to address the `\0` null terminating character and your `count <= arraySize` condition:

```
#include <iostream>

int calcNumber(const char* date, const size_t arraySize) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int count = 0; count <= arraySize; count++) {
        sum += date[count] - '0';
    }
    return sum;
}
int main() {
    const char* p = "1234";
    std::cout << calcNumber(p, strlen(p) - 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining what the problem was, thank you!

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you so much! It might just be my compiler, but when compiling it returns this warning: `tes.cpp:6:31: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]` sorry for the amount of questions, a newbie here!

Answer (score 1):

`date[count]` is a single `char`, perhaps `'3'` (that is [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) code 51, so it is the same as `(char)51`).

To convert that into a small number (e.g. 3), use `date[count]-'0'`

(of course `'0'` is also a `char` constant literal, its value is 48 in ASCII; and the ASCII encoding is such that digits glyphs are encoded by consecutive codes).

BTW, you want to stop on a zero byte (terminating every string). So you could use

```
for (int count=0; date[count] != (char)0; count++) {
    sum += atoi(date[count]); 
}
```

then you don't even need to pass any `arraySize`.

Actually, you are re-inventing (poorly) [`std::atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) (or [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol)). Your `calcNumber` would handle incorrectly strings like `"2X"` (but `std::atoi("2X")` gives 2 which makes more sense). And your `calcNumber` also behaves badly on `"-34"` or on `" 1"`....

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, still produces the same error.

Comment: user0042 odds are good that isak is trying `sum +=atoi(date[count]-'0');` and will get the same error. @isak ,If you want the value of a single digit all you need is `sum +=date[count]-'0';`. No `atoi`required.

Comment: Thank you @user0042 quite a beginner to c++ so all help is greatly appreciated. But would you mind explaining what the - '0' actually does/means, because when running the function having replaced `+=atoi(date[count]-'0');` with `sum +=date[count]-'0';` it returns -32

Comment: @isak It means you substract the char encoded digit value (e.g. ASCII) for `'0'` from the current character to get the corresponding integer number. Character codes for `'0'` to `'9'` are guaranteed to be subsequent.

Comment: @user4581301 The culprit seems to be the `count <= arraySize` condition in combination with the `sizeof(date) / sizeof(date[0])` argument which results in UB.

Comment: @Ron Including the null character in the count to be processed is definitely wrong, but not UB.Ah, No you are right. The `<=` tips it over the edge.